# How to build and create APK for a library module using command line?

Tags: android

In my Android studio project I have a librarymodule (Name:Network-sdk) and have some test cases for the library module. I am creating an automation script for running test cases from the bash for the library module.

I done the following script but its gives test case not found error.

```
#To clean the project
./gradlew clean
#Build the project
./gradlew packageDebug
#Install the APK
adb install ./IrisReferenceClient/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
#Test case which in library module
adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'package.ConnectivityTestSenderTest' package/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Log information:

```
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: package.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunnerINSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{package.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1

        at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:890)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:400)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)
```

I want to know how to build and create APK for file library module and run my test case which in library module.

Comment: have you tried `./gradlew connCheck` or `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest`

Comment: no, I think it will be run the all test cases but in my scenario I want to run test cases one by one using commands.